# OS X Quarantine Folder in Root Directory

Tags: macos, permissions

In my root directory (running macOS High Sierra), there is a folder called `Quarantine` which is owned by the group `499`. I'm not sure what exactly the `Quarantine` folder is, but of more interest to me is the group owner. I can't find any reference online to a group of that name. It isn't even listed as a group when I run `dscacheutil -q group`. Anyone know what the group is?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Judging from the name it sounds like an anti-virus tool is moving quarantined files into there. Just a guess but if you use an AV tool, look there.

Comment: @confetti I think you might be right. I installed McAfee around the time the folder was created. I have since deleted it, which is why I had no clue what it was.

Comment: Another wild guess: There was an actual group with an actual name. Removing McAfee removed the group and that's why now you're left with only the (by-now-deleted) group's number.

Comment: Most likely the `Quarantine` directory wasn't removed because it contains files that were flagged as suspicious or matching a signature.   In many instances, the anti-virus software leaves the decision to the user as to whether to remove them or not.  As such, if you uninstalled it, that file will just sit there until you remove it.  I'd look and see if anything was flagged incorrectly and salvage it before removing the directory.